# My puzzle about getting a function to return a permutation array

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I want to get a method which returns the all the permutations of input string. I have searched the internet and found that most of them are similar to [Robert Sedgewick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sedgewick_%28computer_scientist%29)'s code:http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html

However, I want to return the permutations, not print them. 
Robert Sedgewick's code is copied here:

```
public class Permutations {
    // print N! permutation of the characters of the string s (in order)
    public  static void perm1(String s) { perm1("", s); }
    private static void perm1(String prefix, String s) {
        int N = s.length();
        if (N == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
               perm1(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, N));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       perm1("abcd");
    }
}
```

And the code recoding from Robert Sedgewick's by myself is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static ArrayList<String> permute(String prefix, String s){
        int len = s.length();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(s.length() == 0)
            list.add(prefix);
        else
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                permute(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, len));
        return list;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcd";
        ArrayList<String> array = permute("", str);
        System.out.print(array.size());
    }
}
```

But my code doesn't return the permutations. It returns nothing.  I don't know why. Who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the result of the permute method to the arraylist:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static ArrayList<String> permute(String prefix, String s){
        int len = s.length();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(s.length() == 0)
            list.add(prefix);
        else
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                list.addAll(permute(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, len)));
        return list;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcd";
        ArrayList<String> array = permute("", str);
        System.out.print(array.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because it solves OP's problem with minimal changes, but I'd still recommend [Markus' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16557660/1711796), which is a lot more efficient since it doesn't concatenate `ArrayList`s at each step.

Comment: @Dukeling - I agree, but I try to remember that this isn't http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, I was just trying to show where he went wrong.

Comment: And that's exactly what you should do, but doing so efficiently is the next step to solving problems (even if not required) - I always try to compare efficiency of solutions and try to mention more efficient solutions in my own and other people's answers (either in the form of a link to another answer, an explanation or some code). Remember that going above and beyond is the difference between an acceptable answer and a good / great one. Markus' answer is a better **solution**, but yours is a better **answer**.

Comment: @Dukeling, Hi, thank you so much. I am very interested in the speed of this method with ArrayList, LinkedList and others, I have tested this case with ArrayList and LinkedList and the result is that ArrayList is extremely much more faster than LinkedList. I am not sure with data structure is the fastest for permutation.

Comment: @mitcc This method is slow because it creates an `ArrayList` at every step, and then concatenates them all together, one at a time (with `addAll`). Markus' solution is a lot faster because it only creates one `ArrayList`. Replacing `ArrayList` with `LinkedList` is slower because copying the internal, more complex, structure takes longer (though shouldn't take much longer for Markus' answer, since there's no copying, we're only adding to the end, which is efficient for both a LinkedList and an ArrayList). Any more complex data structure will probably take longer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    /** Return a list of all the permutations of the given string. */
    public static ArrayList<String> permute(String s){
        ArrayList<String> accum = new ArrayList<String>();
        permute(accum, "", s);
        return accum;
    }

    /**
     * Private helper method to do the actual work.
     *
     * @param accum Accumulator of the results.
     * @param prefix The current prefix.
     * @param s The remaining string to permute.
     */
    private static void permute(ArrayList<String> accum, String prefix, String s){
        int len = s.length();
        if(s.length() == 0)
            accum.add(prefix);
        else
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                permute(accum, prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, len));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcd";
        ArrayList<String> array = permute(str);
        System.out.print(array.size());
    }
}
```